# how to create Ansible playbook to obtain OS versions of the remote hosts?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm new to ansible. I have a requirement that requires me to pull OS version for of more than 450 linux severs hosted in AWS. AWS does not provide this feature - it rather suggests us to get it from puppet or chef.

I created few simple playbooks which does not run

```
---
- hosts: testmachine
user: ec2-user
sudo: yes
tasks:
- name: Update all packages to latest
yum: name=* state=latest

task:
- name: obtain OS version
shell: Redhat-release
```

playbook should output a text file with hostname and OS version. Any insight on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `gather_facts: True` is required for most of the answers on this page to work.

Comment: Checkout this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61460151/ansible-not-reporting-distribution-info-on-ubuntu-20-04/70754268#70754268

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use one of the following Jinja2 expressions:

```
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution }}
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution_major_version }}
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution_version }}
```

where:

- `hostvars` and `ansible_...` are built-in and automatically collected by Ansible
- `ansible_distribution` is the host being processed by Ansible

For example, assuming you are running the Ansible role `test_role` against the host `host.example.com` running a CentOS 7 distribution:

```
---
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution_version }}"
```

will give you:

```
TASK [test_role : debug] *******************************************************
ok: [host.example.com] => {
    "msg": "CentOS"
}

TASK [test_role : debug] *******************************************************
ok: [host.example.com] => {
    "msg": "7"
}

TASK [test_role : debug] *******************************************************
ok: [host.example.com] => {
    "msg": "7.5.1804"
}
```

Comment: Hello Gabriel, shouldn't it be "`inventory_hostname` is the host being processed by Ansible" instead `ansible_distribution`?

Comment: Alternatively ```ansible_facts['distribution']``` which returns OS name just like ```{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution }}```

Comment: {{ ansible_distribution }} is enough now, no need to use hostvars explicitly

Comment: is there a way to get the information on a single line?

Answer (score 4):

In a structured way:

```
- hosts: all
  become: no
  vars:
    output_file: os.csv
  tasks:
    - block:
        # For permisison setup.
        - name: get current user
          command: whoami
          register: whoami
          run_once: yes

        - name: clean file
          copy:
            dest: "{{ output_file }}"
            content: 'hostname,distribution,version,release'
            owner: "{{ whoami.stdout }}"
          run_once: yes

        - name: fill os information
          lineinfile:
            path: "{{ output_file }}"
            line: "{{ ansible_hostname }},\
              {{ ansible_distribution }},\
              {{ ansible_distribution_version }},\
              {{ ansible_distribution_release }}"
          # Tries to prevent concurrent writes.
          throttle: 1
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Creates a comma separated file named `os.csv` in execution folder. You can use any variables you want editing `line:`.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible already provides a lot of information about the remote host in the "hostvars" variable that is automatically available.

To see information of your host named "my_remote_box_name", e.g. do

```
- debug: var=hostvars['my_remote_box_name']
```

Some OS information is in

```
hostvars['my_remote_box_name']['ansible_lsb']
```

Which, for one of my ubuntu hosts would be along:

```
{
  "hostvars['my_remote_box_name']['ansible_lsb']": {
    "codename": "xenial", 
    "description": "Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS", 
    "id": "Ubuntu", 
    "major_release": "16", 
    "release": "16.04"
}
```

You can just use those variables in your playbooks and templates, using the "{{ variable_name }}" notation.

```
- debug: msg="My release is {{ansible_lsb.release}}"
```

output:

```
"msg": "My release is 16.04"
```

Answer (score 1):

For a couple of windows instances:

```
    - debug:
        msg:
        - "ansible_distribution {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution }}"
        - "major version {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
        - "version {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution_version }}"
```

gives:

```
ok: [server1] => {
"msg": [
    "ansible_distribution Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard ",
    "major version 6",
    "version 6.1.7601.65536"
]
```

}

```
ok: [server2] => {
"msg": [
    "ansible_distribution Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard",
    "major version 10",
    "version 10.0.14393.0"
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

"AWS does not provide this feature " - you can check file `/etc/os-release` to get details of aws instance.

For example

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Comment: Thanks Vor for the response however, if i were to login to 450 redhat servers and  cat /etc/redhat-release .. i will most likely go nuts in couple of hours.... That was the reason why i wanted to use ansible to automate this. Any Ansible experts here?

Comment: you would also need to use debug to print the stdout from your `cat` command

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: obtain OS version
  shell: Redhat-release
  register: result

- name: print OS version
  debug: var=result.stdout
```

Comment: Thanks smiller171        
I tried the following  
 tasks:
    - name: Collect OS version of Remote host
      shell: cat /etc/redhat-release

    - name: Pring OS Version
      debug: var=result.stdout

TASK [Print OS Version] ********************************************************
ok: [IP] => {
    "result.stdout": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
Var isnot defined came up

Comment: look at my example again. registering the result of your shell command is important.