# Yum module using "pkg5" on single host

Tags: ansible, yum

When running the playbook on all other hosts the pkg_mgr shows as yum, on a single host its showing as "pkg5"

Run against multiple hosts and this is the only one using pkg5

```
[ansible@prdansible01 tanium]$ ansible all -b -m yum -a "name=rsync state=latest"
devenv06 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "pkg_mgr": "pkg5"
    },
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "",
    "rc": 2,
    "results": [
        "> pkg@4.3.7\n> Error! Not more than one entry file/directory is expected\n"
    ]
}
```

I cant seem to find anything on this error or why its happening on this single host?

--

### Update

confirming it is pulling back pkg5, can anyone tell me where that is configured on the host?

```
[ansible@prdansible01 ~]$ ansible -i 10.40.106.192, all -m setup | grep ansible_pkg_mgr
        "ansible_pkg_mgr": "pkg5",
[ansible@prdansible01 ~]$ ansible -i 10.40.106.188, all -m setup | grep ansible_pkg_mgr
        "ansible_pkg_mgr": "yum",
[ansible@prdansible01 ~]$
```

I cant seem to find anything on it.

Comment: You might want to find out where does the variable `"pkg_mgr": "pkg5"` come from. It's [Solaris](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pkg5_module.html#pkg5-manages-packages-with-the-solaris-11-image-packaging-system) package manager.

Comment: [Setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html#setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) gives `ansible_facts.ansible_pkg_mgr` .

Comment: So, most likely, as pointed by @VladimirBotka, running something like [this check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255585/2123530) would explain you the reason

Comment: It is not a configuration you are loooking for, your **OS** is just not the same in that failing host. Try to compare `ansible -i 10.40.106.192, all -m setup | grep ansible_distribution` versus `ansible -i 10.40.106.188, all -m setup | grep ansible_distribution`

Comment: They are both RHEL7.7

Comment: Does the host experiencing this problem have a file `/usr/bin/pkg`? What happens if you rename it?

Comment: @larsks: out of curiousity, do you have any pointer on how the fact is gathered by ansible? I tried to find that in the repo but was not able to pinpoint it exactly.

Comment: On a side note, another way that would not explain the behavior but would fix it, probably, is to use the generic [`package`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html) module instead of the specific [`yum`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) one.

Comment: I believe the `pkg_mgr` fact comes from https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/pkg_mgr.py

Comment: Thing is, I dont want to have to change my playbooks because of a single host that has this issue, Iv 55 dev servers with multiple playbooks and this is the ONLY one with the issue! will be easier for me to rebuild the server but I would be very interested to know where its gone wrong. Dev do have root on their dev servers so someone could have done something to break it.

Comment: @larsks the issue of the OP is quite strange then, from what I read in that module, even if you do have a `/usr/bin/pkg` the conditions based on `ansible_os_family` should override it to `yum` as pointed by the very first comment in here. Warren, what is you version of ansible? `ansible --version`

Answer (score 0):

An extra package was installed by a dev, so the module was defaulting to pkg.

editing the following:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/pkg_mgr.py
```

and moving "{'path': '/usr/bin/yum', 'name': 'yum'}," from the top to the bottom resolved this.

Comment: Excellent, looks like I spotted it :)

Comment: Thanks Larsks! well spotted. Its a fix for now but I still dont understand why it was defaulting to pkg instead of yum when im specifying the yum module.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue and my OS is definitely not Solaris. For some reason it seems to be defaulting to pkg5 even though yum is present and available.

Anyway I just made the change that was suggested and if that does not work I may just have to pull out pkg5 or brute force it to yum!!