# Ansible not reporting distribution info on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ansible-facts, ubuntu-20.04

Example on Ubuntu 18.04 reporting distribution info in 'ansible_facts':

```
$ ansible -i hosts ubuntu1804 -u root -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution*"
ubuntu1804 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution": "Ubuntu", 
        "ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true, 
        "ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/os-release", 
        "ansible_distribution_file_variety": "Debian", 
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "18", 
        "ansible_distribution_release": "bionic", 
        "ansible_distribution_version": "18.04"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

Example of same command against Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ ansible -i hosts ubuntu2004 -u root -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution*"
ubuntu2004 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {}, 
    "changed": false
}
```

Is this an issue with Ubuntu or Ansible?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

Issue resolved with today's update to `ansible 2.9.7`.

Answer (score 2):

After very research to find out Ubuntu 20.04 version then we have got released a version using ansible version-2.5.1

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: System details
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts['lsb']['release'] }}"

  - name: ubuntu 18
    shell: echo "hello 18"
    register: ub18
    when: ansible_facts['lsb']['release'] == "18.04"

  - debug:
     msg: "{{ ub18 }}"

  - name: ubuntu 20
    shell: echo "hello 20"
    register: ub20
    when: ansible_facts['lsb']['release'] == "20.04"

  - debug:
     msg: "{{ ub20 }}"
```